# Designing a word with css using php

Tags: php, html, css

Hey guys am new to css and php .I have been trying to output a php varibale with a custom colour using php.So i have used span tag for acheiving this.But when i tried it it wouldnt worked.

The code which i used is this

```
<?php
$name = "babe";
echo '<p><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold"><?php $name; ?></span></p>';
?>
```

When i run this code i get a blank screen ..

Am i missing something in my code ??

Hope you guys can help me out ..Thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer to solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just delete the PHP code block in $name**.

```
<?php
$name = "babe";
echo '<p><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">' . $name . '</span></p>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it is absolutely wrong.You are starting the php twice. Use the code below to make your code work. You are seeing the blank screen because your code is getting error. Check your error log , i am sure you will find error there.

```
<?php
$name = "babe";
echo '<p><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">'.$name.'</span></p>';
?>
```

or you can use this code too

```
<?php
$name = "babe";
echo '<p><span style="color:blue;font-weight:bold">{$name}</span></p>';
?>
```

Hope this helps you